# Como abreviar "DESISTÊNCIA" E "TRANCAMENTO"

Tags: ortografia, abreviações

Eu tenho que fazer um relatório e não há espaço no relatório para incluir inteiramente as palavras "DESISTÊNCIA" E "TRANCAMENTO". Como o relatório é para uma instituição de ensino gostaria de saber se há alguma regra para abreviar. . Eu não gostaria de colocar T ou D. Gostaria de deixar mais óbvio e incluir uma abreviação para excluir brechas para interpretações.

Answer (score 2):

Não há abreviações estabelecidas para essas palavras<sup>1</sup>, então vale seguir a [regra geral](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/abrev/):

> Basta escrever a primeira sílaba e a primeira letra da segunda sílaba, seguidas de ponto abreviativo. Veja os exemplos:
> bras. (brasileiro), num. (numeral)

que, sabidamente tem muitas exceções, e também regras auxiliares. Esta regra resulta em:

- des. — desistência
- tranc. — trancamento

Em que iniciais maiúsculas também podem ser usadas.

Contudo, num dado trabalho, desde que definidas claramente e sem ambiguidade, há liberdade nas definição de abreviaturas. Aqui, por exemplo, uma possibilidade que talvez ofereça mais clareza é `desist.` para "desistência".

---

<sup>1</sup> De acordo com as listas do [Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa](https://www.volp-acl.pt/index.php/geral/abreviaturas), da [Academia Brasileira de Letras](https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/reducoes), entre outros ([1](https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/abreviaturas-lingua-portuguesa.htm), [2](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/abreviaturas-lista-de-abreviacoes/), [3](https://www.todamateria.com.br/abreviaturas/), ...).